# "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" with raw_input

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm doing the exercises from Zed Shaw's "Learn Python The Hard Way", and exercise 16 just does not seem to want to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# reading and writing files

from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

print "We're going to erase %r." % filename
print "If you don't want that, hit CTRL-C (^C)."
print "Otherwise, press [ENTER] to proceed."

raw_input = ("?")

print "Opening the file...."
target = open(filename, 'w')

print "Truncating the file...."
target.truncate()

print "Enter three lines of input...."

line1 = raw_input("line 1: ")
line2 = raw_input("line 2: ")
line3 = raw_input("line 3: ")

print "Writing to the file...."

target.write(line1)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line2)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line3)
target.write("\n")

print "Closing the file...."
target.close()

# end program
```

For whatever reason, every time I run it, it returns this:

```
mark@mark-KC880AA-ABA-m9150f:/media/KINGSTON/cis-115-09/LPTHW$ python ex16.py ex15Sample.txt
We're going to erase 'ex15Sample.txt'.
If you don't want that, hit CTRL-C (^C).
Otherwise, press [ENTER] to proceed.
Opening the file....
Truncating the file....
Enter three lines of input....
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex16.py", line 24, in <module>
    line1 = raw_input("line 1: ")
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

No matter what I do, the line1 variable seems to be causing the trouble. I've been at it for over an hour now. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code overwrite `raw_input` function in following line:

```
raw_input = ("?")
```

<del>Remove that line.</del>
Replace it with `raw_input('?')`.

---

```
>>> raw_input('line 1:')
line 1:111
'111'
>>> raw_input = ('?')
>>> raw_input('line 1:')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: The problem is the code is meant to be typed exactly as it is in the exercise, and the raw_input('?') is the prompt for whether or not to continue.

Comment: @MBE, Then why do you type it as `raw_input = ("?")` instead of `raw_input('?')`? Is it a typo?

Comment: because it gives the same print-out regardless. The issue doesn't appear to be the raw_input prompt at the beginning, but the one declared at the variable 'line1'

Comment: @MBE The issue is happening at `line1` because you overwrote the function. It's pretty much going `foo = 5; foo = 6; print foo # why isn't this 5?`

Comment: @MBE go back and look at the line in the book again. There is no `=`. Maybe falstru's use of single quotes confused you, but the correct way is `raw_input("?")` or `raw_input('?')`, not `raw_input = ("?")`.

Comment: @Chad That was it. Now I feel like an unappreciative a-hole. Lol, thanks guys, and sorry for wasting your time.... >.< Also, falsetru, I misread your original answer. That's my bad. Thanks for all your help guys! :D